# Throw exception after using Annotation @EnableSpringDataWebSupport

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

Throw exception at saving entity

```
HTTP Status 500 - Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: attempt to create merge event with null entity
```

after using Annotation `@EnableSpringDataWebSupport`. Without annotation all works!

WebConfig

```
 //code
    @EnableSpringDataWebSupport
    public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter
```

//controller

```
@RequestMapping(method = POST, value = "*****")
    public String typeForm(@Valid @ModelAttribute Type,
                           BindingResult bindingResult,
                           RedirectAttributes rAttr)
```

Answer (score 0):

Watch here [Spring Jira](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATACMNS-683). This worked up to and including spring-data-jpa 1.7.2.RELEASE